# Correct way to lock screen orientation across platform versions

Tags: java, android, user-interface, screen-orientation

I realize this is a repeat question, but since Android 2.3+ (Gingerbread) there has not been a definitive answer posted and accepted.

I have code that retrieves the current screen orientation in both my Froyo phone and my Honeycomb tablet.  My questions are:

1. Of the two orientations I retrieve on pre-Gingerbread versions,
   which one should I be using?
2. What methods should I be using to set the orientation/rotation to lock it into place?

Here is the method as I have it now (retrieving, but not setting)

```
protected void lockCurrentOrientation() {

    int orientation;
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    {
        orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        Log.d(LogTag, "Orientation via getConfiguration " + String.valueOf(orientation));

        // Not working - reporting -1 (SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)
        // orientation = getRequestedOrientation();
        // Log.d(LogTag, "Orientation via getRequestedOrientation " + String.valueOf(orientation));

        orientation = display.getOrientation();
        Log.d(LogTag, "Orientation via WindowManager " + String.valueOf(orientation));
    }
    else
    {
        orientation = display.getRotation();
        Log.d(LogTag, "Orientation via Display.getRotation " + String.valueOf(orientation));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to target older versions then use getOrientation(), and if you intend to target newer versions, then use getRotation().  By target, I mean whatever you put in your target sdk in your manifest file.

Comment: My code sample already does that.  I was asking what the right way to SET it is.  In the case of rotation, the documentation says that the value returned is an angle relative to the device's "natural orientation", but the only way I know how to SET the orientation is by setRequestedOrientation passing consts that refer to orienatation values, not angles relative to natural orientation